# Colour a binary image in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, background-color, binary-image

I have a binary image and want to set black to a grayscale colour, e.g. 160, in matlab.

How do I change the colours of a binary image? I understand it is no way to change the color back to original, but only change black and white to gray colors.

Comment: Do you want a grayscale image only (one channel) or do you want an RGB image (three channels) that you're putting grayscale colors into?

Comment: The easiest way is if you're just looking for a one-channel grayscale image. Then `gray_img = uint8(bin_img)*160`

Comment: So you currently have an image with colours ranging from `[0, 1)` or `[0 256)`? Then a simple `image ./ 256 * 160` would rescale from `[ 0 256)` to `[0 160)`.